# Android: drag end drop in grid view (android 4.0 +)

Tags: android

In my app I have a screen with grid view, where I displayed photos, in 2 columns.
I want to add possibility to reorder photos by drag end drop.
I have android 4.0, and I used android native drag and drop:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

So, I already add drag&drop functionality, but the problem is, that I need to scroll grid view when user trying to drag top image to the bottom. That's not a problem to scroll gridView programatically with smoothSctollTo() method, but when i drag item I need to check whether finger at the bottom of the screen or not. The problem is that:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(final View v, final DragEvent event) {
        Log.v("Coordinates", " " + v.getY());
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

All this events called only if one gridview item intersect with another item.
But when I will drag item over clean gridView space, on drag will not called.
How to get finger coords when I drag item ?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement either [DraggableGridView](https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView) or [PagedDragDropGrid](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/pageddragdropgrid/), both of which handle this problem for you.

Edit: Here is a new library that directly extends GridView:
https://github.com/askerov/DynamicGrid

Comment: I've implemented it and would like to have an option to customize, the gridsize, how may i do it?

Comment: @user2459623 I just took a look through the code, and it looks like the columns are automatically determined when the view is drawn. I have updated the post with a new library that extends GridView, allowing you to make customizations just as a normal GridView.

Comment: when we drag grid, other grids change positions themselves, I want to swap any two items, without affectiing others' position. how can it be done? any idea??

Answer (score 0):

from what I know of android I recommend you setup an [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) to the view that you want to scroll, that way if you've reached the bottom of thew view (do some math based on view position and height) you can start scrolling.